# Merge [domains] and [domain] tags

Tags: support, tags

The majority of questions are tagged [domain](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/domain) and only a few this year have been tagged with [domains](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/domains), but the latter does not have a wiki excerpt.

Can we merge the two into [domain](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/domain)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yeah, I have merged the 2 and created a synonym mapping as well